# How do I get gpu assignment working in SLURM through snakemake?

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to make a pipeline with snakemake which involves the use of a gpu and a singularity container for a specific rule. However, while I entered the same resources as I have for performing the action as I have outside of snakemake, I keep running into the following error:
`[guppy/error] main: CUDA error at /builds/ofan/ont_core_cpp/ont_core/common/cuda_common.cpp:278: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE [guppy/warning] main: An error has occurred. Aborting.` 
The information available at the start of the job seems to indicate that there is a gpu available: `Provided resources: mem_mb=7500, mem_mib=7153, disk_mb=1287558, disk_mib=1227911, gpus=1` 
which makes me quite unsure what exactly is going wrong. I have provided the same resources and partition as I would have outside of snakemake, yet it seems to be going wrong.

Here are is the rule that I have made:

```
rule basecalling:
        message:
            "Rule {rule} processing"
        input:
            rules.fast5_conversion.output
        output:
           "{outdir}/guppy_6_5_7_sup/"
        threads: 3
        resources:
            partition="gpu",
            gpus=1,
            mem_mb=7500,
            time="0-0:5:0"
        singularity:
            "docker://genomicpariscentre/guppy-gpu:6.5.7"
        shell:
            "guppy_basecaller -i {input} -s guppy_out/ --device auto --compress_fastq --records_per_fastq 0 --config dna_r9.4.1_450bps_sup.cfg"
```

And this is the config file:

```
cluster:
  mkdir -p ../logs/{rule} &&
  sbatch
    --cpus-per-task={threads}
    --mem={resources.mem_mb}
    --time={resources.time}
    --job-name={rule}-{wildcards}
    --output=../logs/{rule}/{rule}-%j.out
    --partition={resources.partition}
    --gpus={resources.gpus}
default-resources:
  - partition=main
  - mem_mb=1000
  - time="01:00:00"
  - gpus=1
restart-times: 0
max-jobs-per-second: 1
max-status-checks-per-second: 1
local-cores: 1
latency-wait: 60
jobs: 10
keep-going: False
rerun-incomplete: True
printshellcmds: True

use-conda: true
conda-frontend: mamba
use-singularity: true
```

I have tried various ways of adding the GPU, but I have not been able to find a way that will properly link it, as evident by the lack of CUDA recognition.

Comment: Can you post the command line you use to run snakemake? also, check with `sacct -l` what resources are allocated to your jobs.

Comment: I used the following command: 'snakemake --profile bovine_assembly'. This profile is linked to the config file in the post.

When I use sacct -l it seems that I do get allocated to the correct partition, the gpu one, however, I cannot see any mention of a gpu being allocated. Have I made a mistaken in the rule for the allocation of resources?

Comment: Maybe try to salloc and see if you can get another image, like tensorflow, to detect the gpu. https://github.com/sylabs/singularity-userdocs/blob/main/gpu.rst It's hard to tell if the problem is with slurm, singularity, or the guppy command.

Comment: I have tried the guppy command without any container or Snakemake, which worked without a hitch. With some modifications I have gotten it working in a container as well, however, this is using the singularity run command. Which I believe, is not how Snakemake makes a container work?

Comment: After trying out using the guppy command with an exec command in the singularity container, it seems to me that the problem is that "--nv" is not passable to snakemake. When I pass it using '--singularity-args' it tells me the following: 'snakemake: error: argument --singularity-args: expected one argument'.

Comment: My guess is you are calling `snakemake --singularity-args --nv` which is parsed as `--nv` as an option for snakemake.  Try `snakemake --singularity-args "--nv"`.  Also [this issue](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/262) looks relevant, assuming you don't want a gpu on all your rules.